# c4-pedestrian-detector.cpp:283:8: error: ‘Show_Detection_Steps’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compilation

I am trying to compile the CPP file present [here](https://github.com/sturkmen72/C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection/blob/master/c4-pedestrian-detector.cpp) and it is giving me the following error. I am new to this. Any help will be highly appreciated. Also, any other way to compile and run it will be helpful if I am making it wrong.

```
(base) ritika@ritika-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc1xx:~/Downloads/C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection-master$ g++ c4-pedestrian-detector.cpp 
    c4-pedestrian-detector.cpp: In member function ‘bool IntImage<T>::Load(cv::Mat, char)’:
    c4-pedestrian-detector.cpp:283:8: error: ‘Show_Detection_Steps’ was not declared in this scope
         if(Show_Detection_Steps)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code directly in your post, instead of a link to a different website. Also please make sure it is *only* the relevant code, so we don't have to dig through a 1000+ line cpp file.

Comment: Why don't you report this as a bug on that very project page? This is someone else's code, and they can help you to fix it. Not everything _has_ to be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The code you link to is faulty.  It defines `Show_Detection_Steps` (at line 588) after it first uses it (at line 283).  Unless `Show_Detection_Steps` is declared in some header file somewhere.

Comment: BTW I agree with the compiler. It's probably due to VS allowing it as it doesn't have two-phase lookup. Or the other way around, whichever.

Comment: I am in need of a pre-trained model for pedestrian detection for real-time video streaming. My friend gave me link to this file so I was supposed to run and test it. Are you sure that code is faulty?@PaulSanders

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Can you be more clear with what you are saying? I am unable to get you

Comment: @CoryKramer, I compiled the whole cpp file at once whole code is relevant as one part is linked to other one

Comment: I don't know how to be clearer, sorry. The code has a bug. The person who wrote it needs to fix it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I will report the bug once I am assured I am not making any mistake in compiling it

Comment: You're not. You've been told several times now. The code is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is indeed broken; `Show_Detection_Steps` is used before it is declared.

Some compilers let you get away with it due to different methods of implementing templates, which is probably why the author missed it. But the code is, per the C++ language, broken.

You should report this as a bug to the author, using the GitHub project page you linked to.